# During with Present Perfect?

Tags: present-tense, perfect-aspect

Can anyone make this clear for me? Look at this sentence:

-"I have been making this Tshirt during the confinement period"

Let's imagine that the confinement period is not over, and that the job with the Tshirt is over. The question is: can you use "during" in this sentence: I feel you can't, but I can't work out how to express that.

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can. "During" is not an issue. The question is whether you'd feel comfortable saying "I made this T-shirt". If that makes the T-shirt-making process sound like an activity of short duration and you want it to sound like something that took a while, then you'd probably want to use the present perfect -- "I have been making". In that case, what you wrote is fine. But again, "during" is not an issue.

Comment: *I have made this t-shirt during the confinement period.* [I might make more t-shirts during the confinement period. The t-shirt is done but the confinement period goes on.]

Comment: Yes, both  "I made this..." and "I have made this..." are equally right.

Answer (score 1):

There are two meanings to "during" [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/during?q=during),

- "throughout the whole period" and
- "at some point in the period".

Since the confinement period is not finished you must understand as a reader or listener that the second meaning of "during" is the proper one. There is no problem in using "during" if the tense is compatible.

If we take a look at the principle for using the present perfect ([Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/present-perfect-tense/)) we find that there are two possibilities.

> - The action or state that either occurred at an indefinite time in the past.
>     *we have talked before*
> - The action began in the past and continued to the present time.
>     *he has grown impatient over the last hour*

This further advice (same ref.) is the key.

> The important thing to remember about the present perfect is that you can’t use it when you are being specific about when [the action] happened.
>
> - *correct* I have put away all the laundry.
> - *incorrect* I have put away all the laundry this morning.

Since you are being specific about when the action occurred in the past (during the confinement period) you can't use the present perfect. You can't use the past continuous either because it tells of an action in progress in the past, whereas the action is an action that finished in the past.

- I made this Tshirt during the confinement period.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What makes me think it's wrong is the fact that "during" is supposed to be used for finished periods of time, which is not the case. It seems, then, that the Past Simple is the best choice, isn't it? You are specifying "when", regardless of whether that "when" is over or not. Is that it? Thanks again